WordPress meta_query with ACF relationship field
I have a WP custom post type that contains Employee Bio information. Because we don't want to create accounts in wp_users for everyone, this data is implemented as a "regular" CPT living in wp_posts. Let's say I have a row with ID 250 for employee Scott.
We also have normal blog posts. Since we're not using regular WP users, we can't take advantage of the usual metadata and relationships to associate authors with posts. So instead, we have a custom field, "af_author", created with an ACF Relationship field type. When we create a post, we choose an author from the list of Employee Bio objects.
On the page that displays the bio information for an employee, we want to include a list of posts that the employee has authored. So when I'm looking at the Employee Bio page for Scott (ID = 250), I want to do a query loop to retrieve all Posts that have been written by ID = 250. Who the post is written by is stored in the related custom field "af_author" for each post. The field itself is an array of IDs; ID 250 would need to be "IN" the array.
I'm having trouble figuring out how to code the meta query for this. The code below is executed while creating the Employee Bio page, so if employee Scott is being displayed, get_the_ID() would return 250. I have tried the following code with no success:
    $new_query_args = [
        'meta_query' => [
            [
                'key'     => 'af_author',
                'value'   => get_the_ID(),
                'compare' => 'IN',
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $query_args = array_merge( $query_args, $new_query_args );

How do I make this work?

Does the custom field af_author return an array of IDs?

@GS_, af_author is a relationship field, so it's an array.

Based on WordPress query by ACF relationship field, I was able to fix this by changing the 'compare' => 'IN' to 'compare' => 'LIKE'. So the resultant code looks like this:
$new_query_args = [
    'meta_query' => [
        [
            'key'     => 'af_author',
            'value'   => get_the_ID(),
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ]
    ]
];

$query_args = array_merge( $query_args, $new_query_args );

I'm not exactly sure why this works, but it fixed the problem.

There were two reasons 'compare' => 'IN' did not work for you. (1) 'compare' => 'IN' works if value is in array like 'value'   => array('value1, value2').  (2)  As you mentioned, The field af_author itself is an array of IDs. So, meta_query cannot compare the values returned from the af_author in the form of an array by default. I hope I am making it clear.

LIKE works here because Post Object (Field Type in ACF) with Select Multiple stores serialized array in the meta_value field of wp_postmeta table like a:2:{i:0;s:4:"2184";i:1;s:4:"2185";}. So, we know that Like Operator in SQL is used in WHERE clause to search for a specified pattern in a column.

@GS_, what if the serialized value is `a:2:(i:0;s:3:"123";i:1:s:6:"123456";), wouldn't you get a false match on 123456?

Yes, it will return false if matches with 123456. But, if we put the percent signs around the   123456 like '%123456%', thus the pattern matches with serialized value a:2:(i:0;s:3:"123";i:1:s:6:"123456";)
